Is there a concensus on the reason behind the discrepency of neutron decay times?
As some may know, there is a discrepancy of about 10 seconds for the measurement of the decay time of a neutron. This discrepancy exists between 2 methods: the "beam" and "bottle" methods, which have a time of:
Beam neutron decay components time = 887.7s
Bottle neutron decay time = 877.75s
So my question is, is there a consensus now that can explain the discrepancy? What are the leading candidates theoretically and experimentally to explain it.
Also, why was it not able to be predicted by the standard model?

Some discussion at https://physicsworld.com/a/physicists-propose-new-solution-to-the-neutron-lifetime-puzzle/ - there is no consensus, people are still looking at options to resolve things.

@JonCuster interesting, will give it a read! thank you.

What are the error bars?

@Qmechanic In 2018 the difference was about $(9\pm2)\ \rm s$; see e.g. the news story linked from https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/472766/44126

I am a cosmologist/relativist, not a particle physicist, so this is not my area of expertise. To my knowledge, there is no current consensus on the cause of the neutron lifetime anomaly you describe. To quote the Wikipedia article on free neutron decay:

While the neutron lifetime has been studied for decades, there currently exists a lack of consilience on its exact value, due to different results from two experimental methods ("bottle" versus "beam"). The "neutron lifetime anomaly" was discovered after the refinement of experiments with ultracold neutrons.

References identifying the anomaly persist, including some publications done as recently as 2018, and some references to current data referring to publications from 2021, so it doesn’t seem like there’s currently a consensus on this yet.

Why did the Standard Model not predict this? The Standard Model also doesn’t directly predict gravitons, but some of our best theories of quantum gravity predict those too. The Standard Model is exactly that - a model - and it is imperfect. The physics community constantly strives to improve it as much as possible and to make it as accurate a description of reality as it can be, but without a complete description of how the Universe works, we can’t ever be quite sure about everything.

Thank you for this, I'm working on a cold neutron experiment currently, so I wanted to cover all my bases.

You should know that the neutron lifetime is fundamentally linked to polarized quark distribution functions in measured in deep inelastic scattering via the Bjorken Sum Rule (https://www.slac.stanford.edu/pubs/slacpubs/6500/slac-pub-6620.pdf)

Some recent theories speculate that the discrepancy could be linked to dark matter or unknown interactions in particle physics. For instance, some suggest that the presence of a "dark sector" or sterile neutrinos could affect the decay rates, which could result in the different measurements https://www.mdpi.com/2073-8994/16/8/956
